# Using sed to replace substrings between specific tags

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace, xml

I want to combine two sed command in one and really don't know how to do it, I've tried multiple things without success.

For the result I want all slash between a specific tag to be replaced with backslash, what would result in :

Source :

```
<FilePath>a/b/c/d</FilePath> 
<OtherTags>Bob</OtherTags>
<FilePath>1/2/3/4</FilePath>
```

Result :

```
<FilePath>a\b\c\d</FilePath>
<OtherTags>Bob</OtherTags>
<FilePath>1\2\3\4</FilePath>
```

I've found this command to change text between tags :

```
sed -i -e 's/\(<FilePath>\).*\(<\/FilePath>\)/<FilePath>TEXT_TO_REPLACE_BY<\/FilePath>/g' test.txt
```

But this command replace all the text...
So what I want is to keep the text and only replace the slash with backslack with this kind of command :

```
sed -e 's/\\/\//g' test.txt
```

But I struggle to combine those two.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is possible with sed, but difficult. It would be easier with awk and even easier with perl. Is awk available? Perl?

Comment: Can you assume that there are no `<` or `>` inside the tags (and in particular no nested tags)? Otherwise [you really need a library that can parse XML properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Since the whole point of your question is to not replace `/` with ```\``` inside of `<OtherTags>`, it'd have been useful for us testing if you had included in your example lines where the text within `<OtherTags>` included `/`s. Just `Bob` doesn't give us anything to test with to prove if a potential solution works or not. `Bob/Smith` would have been much more useful

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
awk 'match($0,/(.*<FilePath>)(.*)(<\/FilePath>.*)/,a){ gsub("/","\\",a[2]); $0=a[1] a[2] a[3] } 1' file
<FilePath>a\b\c\d</FilePath>
<OtherTags>Bob/Smith</OtherTags>
<FilePath>1\2\3\4</FilePath>
```

The above was run using this input:

```
$ cat file
<FilePath>a/b/c/d</FilePath>
<OtherTags>Bob/Smith</OtherTags>
<FilePath>1/2/3/4</FilePath>
```

Answer (score 1):

command

```
sed -e 's/\//\\/g' -e 's/<\\/<\//g' filename
```

output

```
<FilePath>a\b\c\d</FilePath> 
<OtherTags>Bob</OtherTags>
<FilePath>1\2\3\4</FilePath>
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed with extended regex mode we can progressively match the xml tag FilePath opening and closing on the same line and assuming this tag is not part of quotes or comments.

```
sed -Ee ' :a;s|<(FilePath)>([^/]*(/[^/]*)*)/([^/]*</\1>)|<\1>\2\\\4|;ta' file
```

```
perl -lpe '
 s{<FilePath>\K.*?(?=</FilePath>)}
  <$& =~ tr|/|\\|r>xge;
' file
```

We isolate the portion between the opening and closing of tag and transform the
forward slashes to backslashes in the portion therein.

We can compose multiline regex for ease in expressing the intent.

```
snr='
s|
  <(FilePath)>
   ( [^/]* ([/][^/]*)* )
          /
   ( [^/]* )
  </\1>
|<\1> \2 \\ \4 </\1>|
'
ws=$'\t \n'
sed -E ":a;${snr//[$ws]/};ta" file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the document is a well formed XML document such as

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <FilePath>a/b/c/d</FilePath>
  <OtherTags>Bob</OtherTags>
  <FilePath>1/2/3/4</FilePath>
</root>
```

Then, using `xmlstarlet`, we may convert the forward slashes to backslashes in the values of all `FilePath` nodes:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '//FilePath' -x 'translate(., "/", "\")' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <FilePath>a\b\c\d</FilePath>
  <OtherTags>Bob</OtherTags>
  <FilePath>1\2\3\4</FilePath>
</root>
```

The XPath function `translate()` changes the characters in the 2nd argument (`/`) to the  characters in the 3rd argument (`\`) in the string referenced by the 1st argument (`.`, the current node's value).  The `translate()` function is applied to all nodes matching the XPath `//FilePath`.  This XPath pattern matches `FilePath` nodes anywhere in the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, I'd advise you to use separator other than `/` for `sed` if `/` is presented in your patterns. I personally use `~` for such cases.
The one-liner which suit you needs looks so:

```
 sed '/<FilePath>/s~/~\\~g;/<\\FilePath>/s~<\\~</~' your_file
```

Explanation:
`/<FilePath>/s~/~\\~g` - replaces `/` with `\` in strings containing `<FilePath>` substring. This will replace **all** `/`, so `</FilePath>` will become `<\FilePath>`. In order to revert this one needs the second part of expression - `/<\\FilePath>/s~<\\~</~`

Comment: No, this is not at all what the question requested. The goal is to replace slashes with backslashes only between the tags, not on the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple solution built with a pipeline using sed and tr. It assumes that:

- There are no nested tags inside `<FilePath>…</FilePath>` (the replacement is only performed up to the next `<` after `<FilePath>`).
- `<FilePath>` does not appear inside a literal string (no `<![CDATA[<FilePath>/blah]]>` or `<mytag label="<FilePath>">`).
- Your sed implementation processes the last line correctly even if it doesn't have a terminating newline.

The principle is to use `tr` to switch between `<` and line breaks; that way, when sed processes a “line”, it's actually processing text between one open/close tag and the text open/close tag.

```
tr '<\n' '\n<' | sed '/^FilePath>/ y:/:\\:' | tr '<\n' '\n<'
```

---

Here's a Perl solution. It assumes that:

- There are no nested tags inside `<FilePath>…</FilePath>`.
- `<FilePath>` does not appear inside a literal string (no `<![CDATA[<FilePath>/blah]]>` or `<mytag label="<FilePath>">`).
- `<FilePath>` is always followed by `</FilePath>` on the same line).

The construction is fairly natural: it applies the function `backslashify` to the text inside `<FilePath>…</FilePath>`. The regex `.*?` is a non-greedy match: a greedy match `.*` would replace everything from the first `<FilePath>` to the last `</FilePath>` on the line if there were multiple `<FilePath>…</FilePath>` chunks on the same line. `s:(?!<<)/(?!>):\\:` is a fancier version of `tr:/:\\:` that avoids replacing slashes if they come immediately before `>` or after `<`, which allows nested tags.

```
perl -pe 'sub backslashify {local $_ = $_[0]; s:(?!<<)/(?!>):\\:; return $_} s:(<FilePath>)(.*?)(</FilePath>):$1.backslashify($2).$3:e'
```